# Method that returns the yield for an object in Ruby

Tags: ruby, object, block, yield, chainability

Is there a method in Ruby that returns the content of the block passed on to an object?

For example, what if I have an object which I want to put in an array?

In an ideal world, we would do (what I'm looking for):

```
"string".reverse.upcase.something{ |s| send(s) }
```

which would return an array with my object, as equivalent to:

```
send("string".reverse.upcase)
```

which isn't chainable if I have my object to start with and can get messy in more complex scenarios.

So the `something` method would return the evaluation of the block, like [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249), but for one element only.

Comment: What do you mean by `returns the content of the block passed on to an object`?

Comment: The method would evaluate the content of the block and return it.

Comment: What do you mean by "maintaining chainability"? What is the result of JSON.parse(j)?

Comment: @mlie If you look at the first code chunk, we can reuse the result of the method to pass it on to another method and so on, 'chainability'. If you look at the second code chunk, the code is somewhat more messy since the method is at the beginning. (I'm having difficulty of putting it into words, feel free to edit/comment)

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I think personally that is the other way round: the call in the second line is much clearer to me, the curly braces are difficult to read, and others have to know what `something` means ...

Comment: I see you edited your question, for what I understand you want exactly what `undur_gongor` responded, is that it or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Six years after the original question, Ruby 2.5.0 introduced *`Object#yield_self`*, then shortened in Ruby 2.6 as **`#then`**:

> ```
>  class Object
>    def yield_self(*args)
>      yield(self, *args)
>    end
>  end
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> It executes the block and returns its output.
>
> (*[Ruby Feature #6721](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6721)*)

For example:

```
2.then{ |x| x*x }  # => 4
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of such a thing built-in but you can easily do it yourself:

```
class Object
  def something(&block)
    block.call(self)
  end
end

p "foo".something { | o | [o] }
p 23.something { | x | p x; 42 }
```

gives

```
["foo"]      # object "foo" put into an array
23           # object handed to block
42           # something return block's result
```

Comment: Future readers, this is implemented in Ruby core 2.5.0 as `Object#yield_self`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Object.tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.src/M001035.html) ?

Comment: No, `Object#tap` returns the object that the method is called on, whereas my method would return the evaluation of the block.

Comment: Interesting technique, didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes wish for a similar function in the standard library. The name could for example be `with` or `with_it`

(Repeating previous code with new name)

```
class Object
  def with_it(&block)
    block.call(self)
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map {|x| x * x }.with_it do |list|
   head = list.unshift
   list << head * 10
   list.join " / "
end
```

As opposed to:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map {|x| x * x }
head = list.unshift
list << head * 10
x = list.join " / "
```

While the latter is easier to understand, the former has the benefit of keeping the variables `list` and `head` scoped and the assignment to `x` is more clear in my opinion (the assignment to `x` has to be inserted into the last line of the code). Scoping would be a benfit if the code was a part of a larger method.

Another option to using `with_it` would thus be putting the code in a separate method. Eg:

```
def mult_head_and_join(list)
    head = list.unshift
    list << head * 10
    list.join " / "
end

x = mult_head_and_join [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map {|x| x * x }
```

Not sure what to conclude with here, but I guess I'd vote for with_it to be included in the standard library